# Create Quarterly Subsets in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with a years worth of chronological data. It has other data which are names, amounts, and dates. I want to subset the data frame into yearly quarters to measure certain aspects of the corresponding quarters. Example, I want to see the revenue for only January, February, and March.

I have made sure the dates column is a time series:

```
class(data_frame$launch_date)
>"Date"
```

I have tried this code, to get data from the first quarter / months before and including March:

```
subset(data_frame, format.Date(launch_date, "%m") <= "03")
```

But it does not give me a new data frame and this response:

```
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

And I have tried

```
data_frame_q1 <- data.frame(data_frame, data_frame$launched < as.Date("2013-03-31"))
```

But I don't get a subset frame of the data.

Suggestions?

Comment: Use `lubridate::quarter`.

Comment: Also, just tightening up terminology, you've made sure the dates column is a "Date" class, which is good, but a time series is it's own class and not what you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, but you need to learn how to properly subset data.

A few comments:  don't use `subset`. It works, but you should get used to the more "R" way of doing things. Subset your data frame with `[`. Second, you don't need to call `format.Date` specifically if the argument to the function is a `Date`; you can just call `format`, and R will pick the right function for you.

<s>So, the reason why your function didn't work is because you were comparing to `character` types with `<=` which is not allowed. Convert them to a numeric, and it will work:</s>. I have no idea why your original didn't work. It worked for me.

```
# Generate some data
set.seed(1)
n<-100
data_frame<-data.frame(launch_date=as.Date(Sys.time())+runif(n,1,365))

subset(data_frame,as.numeric(format(launch_date, "%m"))<=3)
```

But, instead of using `subset`, try just using the `[` operator:

```
data_frame[as.numeric(format(data_frame$launch_date, "%m"))<=3,]
```

which just means return all the rows where `as.numeric(format(data_frame$launch_date, "%m"))<=3` is `TRUE`.

If you want to split your data into quarters, you can make a little mapping table:

```
quarters.map<-data.frame(month=1:12,quarter=rep(1:4,each=3))
#    month quarter
# 1      1       1
# 2      2       1
# 3      3       1
# 4      4       2
# 5      5       2
```

And then just `merge` onto it:

```
head(merge(data_frame,quarters.map))
#   month launch_date quarter
# 1     1  2015-01-14       1
# 2     1  2015-01-17       1
# 3     1  2015-01-29       1
# 4     1  2015-01-20       1
# 5     1  2015-01-10       1
# 6     1  2015-01-17       1
```

Comment: "_you were comparing to character types with <= which is not allowed_" - `"02" <= "03"` and `"04" <= "03"`

Comment: Though it can cause stuff-ups, e.g. `"05" < paste0("0",1:10)`

Comment: Indeed, I would avoid it. However, it makes it clear that I can't reproduce OP's error.

Comment: I don't know what the error was either. But this method seems to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Seems to work for me, not sure what you've done:

```
data_frame <- data.frame(
 id=1:5,
 launch_date=seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"),as.Date("2014-05-01"),by="1 month")
)

#  id launch_date
#1  1  2014-01-01
#2  2  2014-02-01
#3  3  2014-03-01
#4  4  2014-04-01
#5  5  2014-05-01

class(data_frame$launch_date)
#[1] "Date"

subset(data_frame, format.Date(launch_date, "%m") <= "03")

#  id launch_date
#1  1  2014-01-01
#2  2  2014-02-01
#3  3  2014-03-01
```

Though it's probably safer to work with actual numbers and do:

```
subset(data_frame, as.numeric(format(launch_date, "%m")) <= 3)

#  id launch_date
#1  1  2014-01-01
#2  2  2014-02-01
#3  3  2014-03-01
```

Answer (score 3):

Just turning my comment into an answer...

```
library(lubridate)
subset(data_frame, quarter(launch_date) == 1)

## Using @thelatemail's data

> subset(data_frame, quarter(launch_date) == 1)
  id launch_date
1  1  2014-01-01
2  2  2014-02-01
3  3  2014-03-01
```

Though I am also confused about what's wrong with your method. Maybe you're not getting the right column name? At the start you use `launch_date`, but in your `data_frame_q1` you use `launched`.

Comment: I think the question was for `<= 3` not `== 3` btw.

Comment: @thelatemail actually `== 1`, in terms of quarters. Thanks for catching!

Answer (score 3):

I would create a new variable for quarters.

```
data_frame$quarter <- quarters(data_frame$launch_date)
```

Then you can subset your data like this:

```
subset(data_frame,quarter=='Q1')
```

Using @thelatemail data:

```
data_frame
  id launch_date quarter
1  1  2014-01-01      Q1
2  2  2014-02-01      Q1
3  3  2014-03-01      Q1
4  4  2014-04-01      Q2
5  5  2014-05-01      Q2

subset(data_frame,quarter=='Q1')
  id launch_date quarter
1  1  2014-01-01      Q1
2  2  2014-02-01      Q1
3  3  2014-03-01      Q1
```

Comment: or all in one step `subset(data_frame, quarters(launch_date)=="Q1")`